# How to set post to draft and not publish if the_content contains certain words?

Tags: php

We need to set posts to draft or to not be created if the_content contains certain words.

This is not something needed on current posts, it is needed on users who publish posts going forward. As an example, if users post a recipe and they have the words "word1" and "word2" within the content area, the post should not be published but set to draft.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Editing to reflect clarifications: prevent unauthorized posts from publishing if they contain certain words.

So I'd make something a little more modular/flexible like this.

```
/**
 * Check if Post Contains Words
 *
 * @param string $content
 * @return bool True if word is found. False otherwise.
 */
function check_for_certain_words( $content ) {
    $words = array('word1','word2');//Your list of words or phrases
    foreach($words as $word) {
        // Case-insensitive search
        if(stripos($content,$word) !== false) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And then to prevent `post` types from being published or scheduled:

```
/**
 * Conditionally Prevents Post from being Published
 *
 * @param int $post_id Post ID
 * @param WP_Post $post Post object
 * @param string $old_status Old post status
 */
function maybe_prevent_post( $post_id, $post, $old_status ) {
    if(check_for_certain_words($post->post_content)) {
        // Sets the post's status back to "draft"
        wp_update_post(array(
            'ID' => $post_id,
            'post_status' => 'draft'
        ));
    }
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'maybe_prevent_post', 20, 3 ); //Hook for publishing post
add_action( 'future_post', 'maybe_prevent_post', 20, 3 ); //Hook for scheduling post
```

I also set the priority for the hooks to be later than the default 10 to ensure they'd be run last.

Comment: Hey, I should have been more clear, sorry for that. This is not something needed on current posts, it is needed on users who publish posts going forward. As an example, if users post a recipe and they have the words "word1" and "word2" within the content area, the post should not be published but set to draft. Hope that is more clear.

Comment: @JohanBarnard thanks! I updated my answer to reflect your clarifications

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think you should use the following hook:

```php
/**
 * Fires when a post is transitioned from one status to another.
 *
 * The dynamic portions of the hook name, `$new_status` and `$post->post_type`,
 * refer to the new post status and post type, respectively.
 */
do_action( "{$new_status}_{$post->post_type}", $post->ID, $post );
```

Code Reference: [`{$new_status}_{$post->post_type}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/new_status_post-post_type/)

So let's see how it works.

```php
/**
 * Set post status to draft
 * if content contains certain words
 *
 * @param $post_id
 * @param $post
 */
function wp_revpey7_post_draft_content_contains_certain_words( $post_id, $post ) {

    $is_contains_certain_words = in_array( true, array(
        is_numeric( strpos( $post->post_content, 'word1' ) ),
        is_numeric( strpos( $post->post_content, 'word2' ) ),
    ) );

    /** check is contains certain words */
    if ( $is_contains_certain_words ) {

        /** set post status to draft */
        wp_update_post( array(
            'ID'          => $post_id,
            'post_status' => 'draft',
        ) );
    }
}

add_action( 'publish_post', 'wp_revpey7_post_draft_content_contains_certain_words', 10, 2 );
```

When a user tries to publish a `post`, it checks if the `post_content` contains certain words. Checks if it contains at least one of the certain words. So this is an `OR` check.

I made a relatively simple and easily extensible check using [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) and [`strpos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) functions. But it can also be implemented using other methods, such as [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), or with PHP8 even [`str_contains`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-contains.php).

And if you want to add an error message too:

```php
/**
 * Add error messages
 * if content contains certain words
 *
 * @param $messages
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
function wp_revpey7_post_content_contains_certain_words_error_message( $messages ) {
    global $post;

    $is_contains_certain_words = in_array( true, array(
        is_numeric( strpos( $post->post_content, 'word1' ) ),
        is_numeric( strpos( $post->post_content, 'word2' ) ),
    ) );

    /** check is contains certain words */
    if ( $is_contains_certain_words ) {

        $error_message = 'Your post was set to draft since you used the word ("%s"), please correct it and try publishing again.';
        add_settings_error( 'is_contains_certain_words_error', '', sprintf( $error_message, implode( ', ', array(
            'word1',
            'word2',
        ) ) ) );
        settings_errors( 'is_contains_certain_words_error' );
    }

    return $messages;
}

add_action( 'post_updated_messages', 'wp_revpey7_post_content_contains_certain_words_error_message' );
```

Comment: Ah just what we needed! Thank you so much. I also adjusted this for one of my other inquiries https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/408832/prevent-post-from-being-published-and-show-error/408855#408855

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but if we wanted to show a small warning when words are found, something like "your post was set to draft since you used the word ("%s"), please correct it and try publishing again. How could this be achieved?